# Why StepVerifer virtual time not works on Flux?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have been using the [lite-rx-api-hands-on](https://github.com/reactor/lite-rx-api-hands-on) tutorial to try to learn about reactor, and I am a bit puzzled by the results of one of the tests, trying virtual time with StepVerifier.

This works perfectly well:

```
@Test
public void expect10Elements() {
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(10))
                .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .expectNextCount(10)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
}
```

But this won't work

```
@Test
public void expect10Elements() {
    Flux<Long> flux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(10);

    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> flux)
                .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .expectNextCount(10)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
}
```

I don't quite understand why this is happening if I am not subscribing to the flux before emitting it in the publisher. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the way the virtual time is implemented.

For explanation see [Reactor Reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_manipulating_time):

> This virtual time feature plugs in a custom Scheduler in Reactor’s
>   Schedulers factory. Since these timed operators usually use the
>   default Schedulers.parallel() scheduler, replacing it with a
>   VirtualTimeScheduler does the trick. However, **an important
>   prerequisite is that the operator be instantiated after the virtual
>   time scheduler has been activated**.
>
> To increase the chances that this happens correctly, the StepVerifier
>   does not take a simple Flux as input. withVirtualTime takes a
>   Supplier, which guides you into lazily creating the instance of the
>   tested flux after having done the scheduler set up.
>
> Take extra care to ensure the `Supplier<Publisher<T>>` can be used in a
>   lazy fashion. Otherwise, virtual time is not guaranteed. **Especially
>   avoid instantiating the Flux earlier in the test code and having the
>   Supplier return that variable. Instead, always instantiate the Flux
>   inside the lambda**.